# How to get device model in AndroidManifest and make condition?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-manifest, sentry

I use Sentry, and last 3 months receive ANR (Application  Not Responding) with two devices (Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite, Samsung SM-A605FN). I think the problem with time waiting for respond(problem maybe occurred  with hardware or slow internet ), and want to make one condition for those two devices for extend timeout time.

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.anr.timeout-interval-mills" android:value="15000" />
</application>
```

I want to set this timeout only for two devices.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please share code for better understanding so it will be easy to resolve your problem. Also please try to make your question more clear and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to opt-out from the auto init, and call `SentryAndroid.init` by yourself to add the condition to the ANR timeout option conditionally by the device the code is running (using the approach from @VivekHande's answer):

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/configuration/manual-init/

Answer (score 2):

In the Android there is a class called Build, which provide all device information

for more information - check [Build Class| Developer.Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build)

Example -    `Log.d("Vivek ", "Device -> " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " Brand ->" + Build.BRAND + " Display -> " + Build.DISPLAY); Log.d("Vivek ", " FINGERPRINT -> " + Build.FINGERPRINT + " Model ->" + Build.MODEL + " Bootloader -> " + Build.BOOTLOADER);`